# How to pass parameters of facet_grid() in a function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, facet-grid

Lets say I have the following dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)    
test_data <- rnorm(40, 4, 3)
factory <- sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 40, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(test_data, factory)
```

And I have a function that creates a graph such as following:

```
graph_builder <- function(data_set, y_axis_parameter, category, attribute_name) {
  graph <- ggplot(data_set, aes(x=seq(length({{y_axis_parameter}})), y={{y_axis_parameter}},
    colour= {{category}})) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(.~{{category}}) +
    ylab(paste0(attribute_name, " Measured Values")) +
    xlab("Data Points") +
    labs(title = paste0(attribute_name)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") 

  graph
}

graph_builder(df, test_data, category, "Test graph" )
```

This code functions correctly in all lines except for facet_grid(). I assumed that passing the column name in double curly braces {{}} would work. However, it appears that facet_grid() does not support passing the column name in this manner.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend passing a raw variable name like `factory`, and feeding that in curly braces to the `rows` and/or `cols` parameters of `facet_grid`:

```
graph_builder <- function(data_set, y_axis_parameter, category, attribute_name) {
    graph <- ggplot(data_set, aes(x=seq(length({{y_axis_parameter}})), y={{y_axis_parameter}},
                                  colour= {{category}})) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      facet_grid(rows = vars({{category}})) +
      ylab(paste0(attribute_name, " Measured Values")) +
      xlab("Data Points") +
      labs(title = paste0(attribute_name)) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") 
    
    graph
  }

graph_builder(df, test_data, factory, "Test graph" )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In R, the `rlang` package's `sym()` function can be used to convert a string into a symbol. We can then use the `!!` operator to unquote the symbol. This allows us to programmatically pass variables to ggplot aesthetics or other arguments which typically do not evaluate strings as variable names. In this case, we can use this method to create a `facet_grid` based on a variable column name.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

graph_builder <- function(data_set, y_axis_parameter, category, attribute_name) {
  y_var <- enquo(y_axis_parameter)
  category_var <- sym(category)
  
  graph <- ggplot(data_set, aes(x = seq_along(!!y_var), y = !!y_var, colour = !!category_var)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(. ~ !!category_var) +
    ylab(paste0(attribute_name, " Measured Values")) +
    xlab("Data Points") +
    labs(title = paste0(attribute_name)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") 

  graph
}

graph_builder(df, test_data, "factory", "Test graph")
```

In the function above `enquo()` is used to quote the `y_axis_parameter` so it can be used in a tidy evaluation context (via the `!!` operator). The `sym()` function is used to convert the category argument to a symbol, so it can be unquoted with `!!` and evaluated within `facet_grid()`.